# Overlaying a JButton onto a JFrame with a JTabbedPan in its content pane?

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

The below code creates a frame with a JTabbedPane in the frame's contentPane and a "Help" button added directly to the frame's layered pane - at a higher index than the default, so it should always be painted in front of the tabbed pane.  But as you can see if you run it, as soon as you click on one of the tabs (or, on Mac, as soon as you hover over a tab), the "Help" button gets painted over - i.e. disappears.  You have to resize the frame to make the "Help" button re-appear.

Is this a Java bug or am I doing something wrong?  If the latter, what needs to be done to fix the problem?  I've consulted both https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html .

Please pardon the poor positioning of the "Help" button.  I was just trying to write a quick test to include here.  The idea is the to overlay a "Help" icon button in the unused space of the JTabbedPane.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class TabTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
                tp.addTab("hello", new JPanel());
                tp.addTab("there", new JPanel());
                frame.getContentPane().add(tp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                JLayeredPane layeredPane = frame.getRootPane().getLayeredPane();
                JButton helpButton = new JButton("Help");
                helpButton.setBounds(800, 5, 50, 20);
                layeredPane.add(helpButton, 400);
                frame.setSize(new Dimension(900, 800));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the `glassPane` instead, would give the same desired result without the hassle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding with `JLayeredPane`.

If you have a look at the JavaDocs for `Container`, you will note that there are (at least) two `add` methods

- [`Container#add(Component, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-int-)
- [`Container#add(Component, Object`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-)

The question you need to answer is, which one are you actually calling?

Both the [JavaDocs for `JLayeredPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html) and [How to use JLayeredPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) demonstrate that you should be calling the second one.

While the first can affect the z-ordering of the components, it's no guarantee that the component positions won't be changed.

Instead of:

```
layeredPane.add(helpButton, 400);
```

you should be using:

```
layeredPane.add(helpButton, new Integer(400));
```

which will pass the value as a constraint to the container, instead of the desired position within the container hierarchy - yeah, suitable I know

An alternative solution might be to use the `glassPane` instead, for example...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
tp.addTab("hello", new JPanel());
tp.addTab("there", new JPanel());
frame.getContentPane().add(tp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

// Null layout used here for demonstration purposes only
JPanel glassPane = new JPanel(null);
glassPane.setOpaque(false);
frame.getRootPane().setGlassPane(glassPane);
// This is important, as setGlassPane makes it invisible
glassPane.setVisible(true);

JButton helpButton = new JButton("Help");
helpButton.setBounds(800, 5, 50, 20);
glassPane.add(helpButton);

frame.setSize(new Dimension(900, 800));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: OMG - can't believe I got bit by this again (now that you mention it, I remember doing the same mistake some years ago!)  Thanks so much!

I can't use the glass pane because it's already being used for something else.  Again many thanks.

Comment: @user1496859 If I had a dollar for each time I've done this without thinking, I'd be retired on deserted island :/